# counting selective data for an id

Tags: sql, oracle

I wanted to know the best way to solve the below scenario, where I've an ID and a state in one table. 
Accepted is the end state, once the state reaches accepted for a particular ID no further updates will occur for that ID.

For example, this is how the table looks

```
ID   | State
-----+----------------    
12   | Not Accepted
12   | Not Accepted
12   | Accepted
45   | Not Accepted
67   | Not Accepted
```

Now, I want to count distinct ids into Accepted and Not Accepted buckets.

If an `id` reached the accepted state, then it should be counted in `accepted` bucket (ignoring the fact it has "not accepted" states earlier). Example for id = 12 has 2 non accepted states and 1 accepted state so only the count of `accepted` should be incremented.

Expected result

```
Accepted | Not Accepted
---------+--------------
    1    |      2
```

I tried is this SQL statement, but it doesn't give me the correct result

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN state = 'Accepted' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS accepted,
    SUM(CASE WHEN state != 'Accepted' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS nonaccepted
FROM 
    SAMPLE;
```

Results I get:

```
Accepted | Not Accepted
---------+-------------
    1    |      4
```

Comment: 1) It's totally unclear what you're asking. Please post the SQL you've attempted to do this yourself, include the results you're getting from that query, and more clearly state the problem. 2) While you're making that [edit], improve your title to state the problem or question you're asking. If you remove the tag information (SQL and Oracle) which is redundant, it leaves *Basic*, which has zero value or meaning. Your title should clearly state the problem you're having or the question you're asking, and should be meaningful to future readers who see it in a set of search results See [ask].

Comment: You are a champion, Vik! I edited your post to format it properly - I see you edited again to remove the formatting. Good on you mate!

Comment: I'm sorry @mathguy, i did not intend to remove your formatting i was already in edit mode to make it more sensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you are asking for but I think you want this:

```
select sum(case when min_state = 'Accepted' then 1 else 0 end) accepted_cnt,
       sum(case when min_state = 'Not Accepted' then 1 else 0 end) not_accepted_cnt
from (select id, min(state) min_state
      from my_table
      group by id);
```

Comment: thanks @Art Trifonov